# Make an alias column with custom string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, select, alias

I have a MySQL tables like this:

```
##customer##
+-----------+----+---------+
|customer_id|name|telephone|
+-----------+----+---------+
|     1     |Andi|+62932011|
|     2     |Boby|+62928291|
|     3     |Jane|+62932212|
|     4     |John|+62999021|
|     5     |Beth|+62999021|
|     6     |Noel|+62999021|
+-----------+----+---------+

##plus_membership##
+-----------------+-----------+-------+------------+
|plus_membership_id|customer_id|status |requested_at|
+------------------+-----------+-------+------------+
|        1         |     1     |   1   | 2018-11-01 |
|        2         |     2     |   0   | 2018-11-03 |
|        3         |     4     |   2   | 2018-11-04 |
|        4         |     6     |   1   | 2018-11-05 |
+------------------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

there are two tables in above structure, the first is the `customer` with `customer_id` as the primary key and the second one is the `plus_membership` which has foreign key `customer_id`, the `plus_membership` table is a table to show a request if customer request to become a plus member, status `1` means the customer is apporved to be plus member. I need to select the customer table and add alias column lets say the alias column name is membership , that shows only `regular` or `plus` , `plus` means the customer in `plus_membership` status is `1`, and regular if customer doesnt exist in `plus_membership` table or status is not `1` in membership table. for example:

```
SELECT *, .... AS membership FROM customer;

+-----------+----+---------+----------+
|customer_id|name|telephone|membership|
+-----------+----+---------+----------+
|     1     |Andi|+62932011|   Plus   |
|     2     |Boby|+62928291|  Regular |
|     3     |Jane|+62932212|  Regular | 
|     4     |John|+62999021|  Regular |
|     5     |Beth|+62999021|  Regular |
|     6     |Noel|+62999021|   Plus   |
+-----------+----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Can there be multiple entries for a specific `customer_id` in the `plus_membership` table ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya no only 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Left Join` between the two tables, and use [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) conditional expressions to evaluate `membership` accordingly.

`Left Join` would ensure that all the customer(s) from the `customer` table are considered, whether they have a corresponding matching row in the `plus_membership` table or not.

```
SELECT
 c.customer_id, 
 c.name, 
 c.telephone, 
 (CASE WHEN pm.status = 1 THEN 'Plus' ELSE 'Regular' END) AS membership
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN plus_membership AS pm 
  ON pm.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

---

Another approach can be using [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) and [`Exists()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). Generally, this *would be* less efficient than Left Join approach.

```
SELECT 
  c.customer_id, 
  c.name, 
  c.telephone, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM plus_membership AS pm 
                    WHERE pm.customer_id = c.customer_id AND 
                          pm.status = 1
                   )
       THEN 'Plus' 
       ELSE 'Regular' 
  END AS membership 
FROM customer AS c
```

Answer (score 1):

We use `EXISTS` or `IN` to look up data in another table.

```
select customer_id, name, telephone,
  case when customer_id in (select customer_id from plus_membership where status = 1)
       then 'Plus' else 'Regular' end as membership
from customer
order by customer_id;
```

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya: As long as there are no performance issues, why worry? This kind of task is best addressed with `EXISTS` or `IN`. A solution with an outer join is possible, but obfuscates that we are merely selecting customers plus a flag. And it only works here, because the OP told you that there can only be one row per customer in the other table. (Which makes me wonder if this is guaranteed to stay so forever and why there are two tables at all.) `IN` does exactly the same as `EXISTS` here. So it would be a poor optimizer, if it came up with different execution plans. Maybe it's that poor.

Comment: Oops, where has the comment gone I am answering to? :-)

Comment: I removed the comment, because I added the Correlated subquery solution to my answer :)